# How can I export and store light curves?

Tags: modifiers, video-sequence-editor, video, color-management

It is easy do color correction/grading (Add -> Effect Strip -> Adjustment Layer, then Modifiers -> Add Strip Modifier -> Curves). This can be used for instance to give a "sunset look" to an amateur video that had a blueish look.

[image]

Once I have created some color curves, how can I export them so that they can be imported and re-used in different projects?

Comment: Currently there is no way to export curve data. An addon would need to be made.

Answer (score 3):

I would encourage you to start with the CDL node, as it is easy to replicate and generate looks that can be loaded with OpenColorIO.

If you are using a complex node chain to modify an image, you can reuse your crafted looks. It will require a bit of learning and patience. If you wish to dive into this subject, feel free to wade through [this longwinded post written by an idiot](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65948/how-to-make-3d-luts-and-use-them-in-blender). Also note, [Blender's curves (and the entire UI) isn't colour managed by and as a result it is not likely responding the way that one might believe it is](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Sobotka/Color_Management/Bent_Curves).

[This post over at Blender Artists is quite useful as well](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?428779-Colour-Science-(Was-Blender-Filmic)&p=3209866&viewfull=1#post3209866).

Comment: Additional info here: [What is the the ASC-CDL node?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55231/what-is-the-the-asc-cdl-node)

Comment: Read also: [**CDL 101**](http://mikemost.com/?p=299#more-299)

Answer (score 2):

Any node or node set can be saved as its own reusable entity. Just select the curve node and hit ctrl-G and you can name and reuse the node group in any other material using shift-A / Search or Groups.

Something very much like this: [Grab shader color to mix in another shader?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101330/grab-shader-color-to-mix-in-another-shader)

In addition, you can gather those node groups in a blend file and link them from other blend file. Basically creating your own library: [How to import Downloaded Materials/Files?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63018/how-to-import-downloaded-materials-files)