# How can I have a "constant variable" for multiple Materials

Tags: materials, node-editor

I have many of different materials, and they each need to have a mix factor changed all at once. I do not want to animate all of them separately. Is there any way to use one thing for all of them?

Comment: Use node group: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99182/how-can-i-export-and-store-light-curves/101783#101783